# What means "way" of an "m-way, n-dimension tensor"?

Tags: tensors, tensor-decomposition

In a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.01375) the author uses the term *m-way* in the context of tensors without defining it. It cannot be the tensor dimension as the whole sentence says:

"Let $\mathcal{A}$ represent an $m$-way, $n$-dimension symmetric tensor."

What is meant by $m$-way?

[image]

Comment: The shape of the tensor is $n \times n \times \dots \times n$, where the $n$ is repeated $m$ times. For example, if $n=10$ and $m=3$ then the tensor is $10 \times 10 \times 10$

Comment: @NickAlger In your example I would rather call $m$ to be a dimension, but the author uses already $n$ for the dimension.

Comment: @granularbastard the author of your preprint refers to [Comon et.al.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1681.pdf) who define $k$-way more clearly. A $1$-way tensor is then a vector, a  $2$-way tensor is a matrix, and so on. This used to be called "rank" or "order". Old wine in new (machine learning ?) wineskins.

Comment: By the way, in representation theory and other areas it's common to use the language of an $m$-fold tensor to mean $V^{\otimes m} = V \otimes \cdots \otimes V$ with $m$ tensor factors.

Comment: I've also seen the terminology "m-mode"

Comment: @KurtG. If a 1-way tensor is a vector, then it has dimension 1 but the author speaks about an $m$-way, $n$-dimension tensor. Your example says, that "way" means the same as "dimension".

Comment: I do not think so. A vector has one index and its dimension is the number of its components. A vector in $\mathbb R^n$ is an element of an $n$-dimensional space. Sure, a vector spans a one-dimensional subspace but I don't think tensor people mean that. Anyway, no matter how we call that stuff. Number of indices and range from which every individual one is taken is all that counts.

Comment: @KurtG. A $3\times3$ matrix is a 3-way tensor with 2 dimensions?

Comment: No. A matrix is a $2$-way tensor. Regardless if it is $2\times 2$ or $10\times 10$ or whatever. Forget about "dimension" it is just confusing.

Comment: @KurtG. If a matrix is a 2-way tensor what is meant by the author's terminology "m-way, n-dimension tensor"?

Comment: $m$-way means this tensor carries $m$ indices $i_1,...,i_\color{red}{m}$ each of which is from the set $\{1,..,\color{red}{n}\}$ ($n$-dimensions if they will).

Comment: Please do not use "rank" or "way" but "order".

Comment: @RainerGlüge "rank" is bad, but "way" is better than "order". The problem with "order" is that nothing is being ordered. It makes things confusing when you talk about re-ordering the modes of a tensor, or re-ordering a sequence of tensors (both common operations).

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the commentaries, $m$-way means that the tensor carries $m$ indices $i_1,\ldots i_m$ each of which is from the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

That the author in the mentioned paper calls $n$ a dimension is a little bit awkward.

Rather, I would call $m$ a dimension and $n$ I would call the number of elements per dimension.